# Split data frame for scatter plots individually

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

A simple data frame shows data of Teams in Departments for different games.

I want to split this data frame by Team, and make scatter plots on their Score and Mark.

[image]

It seems work fine when viewing the plots on screen. However when saved them as files. Strange thing happened (Rabbit has 6 dots rather than 3).

[image]

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Department':['Buy','Buy', 'Trade', 'Trade', 'Trade', 'Buy'],
               'Team':['Lion','Lion','Rabbit','Rabbit','Rabbit','Lion'],
               'Game':['a352','a425','a845','a846','a235','a526'],
               'Score':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
               'Mark':[1,3,5,7,1,2]}, columns = ['Department','Team','Game','Score','Mark'])

for each in df.groupby('Team'):
    plt.scatter(each[1]['Score'], each[1]['Mark'])
    plt.savefig('C:\\' + str(each[0]) + '.png')
```

What's the right way? Thank you.
(btw, what's the better way rather than "each[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUYgy.png)['Score']"?)

Comment: What is the Strange thing you are referring to?

Comment: @ggrelet, when saved to files, Rabbit has 6 dots rather than 3.

Comment: Ok so Rabbit plots Rabbit data **and** Lion data on the same graphe. I suspect that it's because `plt` use the same `figure` on your `for` loop.  
Try to add `plt.figure()` at the entrance of the loop and then `plt.close()` at the exit (i.e. the end) of your `for` loop.

Comment: (removed since I posted exactly what @ggrelet said)

Comment: thank you both ggrelet and Asmus. Do you want to post an answer so that I can choose?

Comment: I'm going to do it, yes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rabbit plots Rabbit data and Lion data on the same graph.

I suspect that it's because `plt` use the same figure on your for loop. Try to add [`plt.figure()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) at the entrance of the loop and then [`plt.close()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html) at the exit (i.e. the end) of your `for` loop to create and close a new `figure` each time.

Like this:

```py
for each in df.groupby('Team'):
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(each[1]['Score'], each[1]['Mark'])
    plt.savefig('C:\\' + str(each[0]) + '.png')
    plt.close()
```